# Localized drawable not showing accordingly to its locale

Tags: android, localization, drawable, android-drawable

I'm struggling with **drawable localization**. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization), I see that drawables can be localized in a language-specific folder, simply putting the region identifier "**-langCode**"  (in my case -it) after the drawable folder name. I've defined inside my res folder a drawable-it folder, with the localized resource inside. The resource has the same name it has in the drawable "without prefix" folder but I can't see it in the Android project view from Studio and it isn't shown both in preview layout and when I run my app on a phone with italian language set. Am I missing something from the documentation?

[image: localized drawable issue]

Comment: Please try to set image in following folders: drawable-it-mdpi,
drawable-it-ldpi,
drawable-it-hdpi,
drawable-it-xhdpi,
drawable-it-xxhdpi,
drawable-it-xxxhdpi

Comment: Perfect man, it works! Wasn't clear from the docs. Post the answer i'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to set image in following folders:

- drawable-it-mdpi
- drawable-it-ldpi
- drawable-it-hdpi
- drawable-it-xhdpi
- drawable-it-xxhdpi
- drawable-it-xxxhdpi